# How to test for a state change after image element load event?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I have the following code:

```js
return (
    <img
        ref={imgRef}
        src={url}
        alt={alt}
        onLoad={() => {
          if (imgRef.current?.naturalWidth) setIsImgLoaded(true);
        }}
        style={!isImgLoaded ? { display: 'none' } : {}}
    />
```

So when the image finishes loading (by checking its `naturalWidth`), I update the `isImgLoaded` to `true` and display it (at the beginning, as you can see, I have `display: none` set for the image).

In my tests, whenever I try to do:

```js
expect(screen.getByRole('img')).toExist()
```

I get an error `TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find role="img"` , even if I try to use `waitFor` or `findByRole`.

What can I do?

Comment: And did you check if the `img` actually renders on the DOM outside of a unit test environment?

Comment: Yes I checked, it does.

Comment: Can you use the `debug` method in the unit test and print to the console ? `const  {  debug } = render(<Component />); console.log(debug())` I suspect if the element is getting rendered while unit testing. This should confirm that part.

Comment: I don't think `debug()` works inside of `console.log()`.
When i put `screen.debug()` inside of my test, it shows the `img` element.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly trigger the image's `onLoad` event to trigger its callback and make the image visible during the test.

```js
test("image is visible after loading", () => {
    render(<TestComponent />)
    // Use `{ hidden: true }` to access the image while it's not visible
    const image = screen.getByRole('img', { hidden: true })
    fireEvent.load(image)
    // No longer requires `{ hidden: true }` as the image is now visible
    expect(screen.getByRole('img')).toBeInTheDocument()
});
```

Comment: `naturalWidth` of the img ref stays at `0` (although i gave it a valid img URL)

Comment: You'll probably need to set that too explicitly in your test.